# Problem with StandardScaler on SVM classifier model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm using a support vector machine as a classifier for financial market data

I have a database with 1500 data records

then I do the pre-processing and division and training and testing

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42, stratify = y)

scaler = StandardScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

but to maintain good control, I save the training file with the pickle

then I upload the file to another database with new data (about 150)

I also perform the standardscaler on the new data

when I run the model and perform the accuracy test, I get 60%, as an example

my problem is as I increase this new database, going from 150 to 151, 152, 153 and so on

when incrementing new data, I notice that the model loses accuracy and even previous classifications are different, when I classified it as 1 it was 0 or the other way around

I suspect that with new data, the dimensionality of the scaled data becomes different

I want that when inserting new data, the previous data does not have new ratings 0 and 1, and consequently worsens my initial accuracy

can anyone help solve this?

Comment: Please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code snippets (*not* as italic text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally we can only speculate due to insufficient information. The thing is, that I deduce from the fact that its predictions change that you are not simply transforming the new data with the current scaler, but you are fitting and then transforming the data. So, long story short, you need to export your scaler as a pickle, then load it when you process your new data and simply transform (no fitting!) these [150, 151, ...] instances.